# Iso4app parameters in QGIS

Tags: qgis, isochrone

In Iso4app QGIS plugin, in the isochrone parameter window, how speed type and speed limit work?
do they work based on the maximum allowed speed of the roads? or if we determine a speed level more than maximum allowed speed of the road in the speed limit field it would create isochrones based on the entered speed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Speed type** parameter acts on the speed allowed on the roads. It can assume the following values:
**Very low**: intense traffic
**Low**: traffic
**Normal**: little traffic
**Fast**: the maximum speed allowed on the road is used.

**Speed limit** parameter is used to indicate that the vehicle in any case cannot exceed this speed.
In order to simulate a moped the speed limit can be set to 50km/h, if a road allows you to go at 90km/h the system considers for that road the limit of 50km/h.
If another road allows only 30km/h being less than 50km/h however the system considers for that road the limit of 30km/h.

For a moped it is also useful to check the parameter Reduce queue time.